# Naming a named function in an angular controller

Tags: angularjs

So I've been using named functions like this on my projects:

```
angular
    .module('meanhotel')
    .controller('HotelsController', HotelsControllerFn)

//HotelsControllerFn.$inject = ['']

function HotelsControllerFn(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'MEAN Hotel App';
}
```

But suddenly, I'm getting errors like

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module meanhotel due to:
ReferenceError: HotelsController is not defined
```

Which forces me to rename my function the same as the controller, (and then everything works).

```
angular
    .module('meanhotel')
    .controller('HotelsController', HotelsController)

//HotelsController.$inject = ['']

function HotelsController(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'MEAN Hotel App';
}
```

Any wisdom or insight on this? I thought I could name the function anything I wanted...

Comment: are you using gulp or grunt as build tools?

Comment: In past projects I was. This project just links to the javascript files directly from index.html. So that's the difference!

Comment: actually i was thinking they were cause of problem ... can't see why it makes a difference otherwise so long as named function matches reference argument

Comment: Yep. It makes no sense.

Comment: remind me when I'm traveling not to stop at "Mean Hotel"...sounds evil. When's the movie coming out?

Comment: Udemy project - that's just what they call it. Very simple CRUD app, but it teaches GeoJSON and jwt authentication, so I'm doing it...

Comment: Hmm should be okay, do not need to rename/refactor the function. What version of angularjs do you use man?

Comment: 1.5.8 - the latest

Answer (score 1):

When you do angular.module without [] parameter you retrieved an existing module. In your code somewhere you have reference to function named HotelsController. As module is not able to trace it it must be throwing an error.

If you change your reference or create module like this it should start working.angular
    .module('meanhotel',[])
    .controller('HotelsController', HotelsControllerFn)

Comment: in another file (where I config the routes) I DO set the angular module with the [] brackets. So in this file here I am definitely  trying to reference the same module. Problem is, it seems not to be referencing it UNLESS I name my functions a certain way.

Comment: I think within your module you have reference of the function that you are trying to rename. As it is not creating a seperate module it expects you to define that function. If full code is available I might be able to comment further.

Comment: This is correct and I finally found where it was happening. Thanks sir!